# How to disable analyzing code coverage for libraries

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

When I run tests in CLion with code coverage, I get results not only for my code, but also for GTest library. Because of this CLion shows that only 25% of lines in my project are covered. Most of the lines are located in `cmake-build-debug-coverage/googletest-src/googletest` with code coverage of 24%. I've added GTest to CMake the way it is suggested in its repository:

```
if (BUILD_TESTING)
    include(FetchContent)
    FetchContent_Declare(
            googletest
            GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/google/googletest.git
            GIT_TAG release-1.12.1
    )
    FetchContent_MakeAvailable(googletest)

    add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}_test
            test/matrix_test.cpp
            src/matrix.cpp)
    target_compile_features(${PROJECT_NAME}_test PUBLIC cxx_std_17)
    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}_test GTest::gtest_main)
    target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}_test PRIVATE include)

    include(GoogleTest)
    gtest_discover_tests(${PROJECT_NAME}_test)
endif ()
```

How can I make CLion show code coverage only for my code, excluding any libraries?

Answer (score 0):

One way of solving this problem is to disable compiler flags `-fprofile-instr-generate -fcoverage-mapping`, which are added by CLion, during the build of GTest library. They are stored in `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` variable. So, this variable can be first cleared and then restored back like so:

```
if (BUILD_TESTING)
    # Exclude gtest library from code coverage analyzer
    set(${PROJECT_NAME}_CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS, ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS})
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "")

    ...

    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS ${${PROJECT_NAME}_CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS})
endif ()
```

After this code coverage shows 100% coverage for the project as expected